# How to visualize numpy.zeros array as an RGB image?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am working on Ubuntu using python 2.7 with OpenCV
I am trying to display 4 images in the same window.
Because opencv does not have any function for this I will try to make one.
I have search in Stack Overflow and I found some complicated solutions but generated in C/C++ which I do not know.

So, my strategy is:
I have 4 color BGR images. All 4 same size: (x,y)
I will generate a numpy array of zeros 4 times the size of the original images (2x,2y)
I will copy each images in the numpy zero array, but in different position, so they will look each image next to the other:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def ShowManyImages():




    img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png',1)
    img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png',1)
    img3 = cv2.imread('img3.png',1)
    img4 = cv2.imread('img4.png',1)

    x,y,_ = img1.shape
    print x, y   # show: 500,500
    img_final = np.zeros((x*2, y*2, 3), np.uint8)
    print img_final.shape   # show: 1000,1000,3
    img_final[0:500,0:500,:] = img1[:,:,:]

    cv2.imshow('final', img_final)


    cv2.waitKey()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



ShowManyImages()
```

However, the code does not show any image. I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Note: to make the code shorter, I only show the code for the first img (img1)

Comment: Using `numpy.bmat` might be cleaner giving a numpy.matrix that would need conversion to array.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I did not know this option. I tried bmat but I got an error message: 'ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.' I went to the documentation and I undersand is only for 2D arrays?'out : matrix

    Returns a matrix object, which is a specialized 2-D array.
'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with few `stack` operations assuming `a0,a1,a2,a3` as the four `3D` (RGB) image arrays -

```
a01 = np.hstack((a0,a1))
a23 = np.hstack((a2,a3))
out = np.vstack((a01, a23))
```

Sample run -

```
In [245]: a0 = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,3))
     ...: a1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,3))
     ...: a2 = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,3))
     ...: a3 = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,3))
     ...: 

In [246]: a01 = np.hstack((a0,a1))
     ...: a23 = np.hstack((a2,a3))
     ...: out = np.vstack((a01, a23))
     ...: 

In [247]: out.shape
Out[247]: (4, 6, 3)
```

Thus, we would have them stacked like so -

```
a0 | a1
-------
a2 | a3
```